# How to prove mathematically that the work done during irreversible process is least due to viscosity stress?

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

This is a known fact that the work done by the system is maximum during reversible processes & least during irreversible processes owing to the viscosity stresses. But can we prove it mathematically?

For that I have taken an ideal gas of mass $m$ in a piston-fitted cylinder. Suppose the viscosity coefficient is $C$ & is proportional to the time-rate change of volume of the gas. So, viscosity $$f_v = -C\dfrac{dV}{dt}$$. Let the initial & final pressures are $p_i$ & $p_f$ . So, the external force is $$F = (p_i - p_f)A$$, $A$ being the area of the piston. The restoring force provided by the gas is $$F_R = -k(p_i - p)A$$, $p$ being temperature at any time $t$. Now, the forces can be equated as $$F = F_R + f_v \implies (p_i - p_f)A=-k(p_i - p)A -C\dfrac{dV}{dt}$$.

Now, what I should do to show the required result? Are the results different for compression & expansion?

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand what you are asking.  A reversible process has conservative forces, thus the path integral is independent of path.  Meaning, the change in energy is independent of path.  Introduction of an irreversible effect can create entropy.  So are you asking about the laws of thermodynamics (i.e., relating work to changes in internal energy and entropy)?

Comment: @honeste_vivere: Check [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/reversible-vs-irreversible-gas-compressionexpansion-work/). My equations, however, aren't same as that of him.

Comment: Okay, I am not sure I follow "Chester's" comments/arguments, but I did not spend a lot of time looking at his long winded explanation.  In any case, one can always try to keep it simple and just use the standard tests for local maxima and minima (i.e., partial derivatives).